# Content Delivery Network for html2canvas?

Tags: html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas & jsPDF without installing Node.js
(this also because I will add the html pages to a Wordpress site, and want to avoid issues).
While jsPDF offers several "script src url" options,
I see that html2canvas used cdnjs.cloudflare as url only till its version 0.5.0-beta4
(https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4).
Looking at latest versions (1.0.0) the Author offers only npm, Yam or local download.
After some research I found that the script is hosted in jsdelivr, open source cdn
(https://www.jsdelivr.com/).
Selecting among several options there is "https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/html2canvas"
where f.e. (among options) you can include:

```
<script src:"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-alpha.12/dist/npm/index.js"></script>
```

or for multiple you can apply the suggested code:

```
[![](https://data.jsdelivr.com/v1/package/npm/html2canvas/badge)](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/html2canvas)
```

I'm rying to use this system, but not sure if I am really including the whole package or not
(there are many issues:
since html2canvas combined with jsPDF is a scipt "in progress", I don't understand when the
issues depend on some my mistake or on real issues).
Can s/one help me comforting the jsdelivr/npm solution? Do I include all with "index.js"?
Thank you in advance.